# How can I know inside or outside tap release on a view/Shape in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I want to know if user did release the drag gesture inside View or out side, for this reason I just worked for local and it is working, I wanted finish for global, but I saw that I would be need to read the parent Size, the location and the size of child also some math work to know if the tap release was inside or out side the view, So I was not sure if there is a simpler way for this, that is why asked to know, the current view is just a simple Rec, but it would needed more math work if it was Circle or what I should do with a custom path Shape? I cannot hard coded multiple if for a custom path, which that condition would not usable for deferent custom path! So what is the logical and best way for this job?

*PS: My focus is not finding answer for global coordinateSpace, I can do it by myself, but that would not useful if my view was Circle, or a custom path! I want find out a basic and general way for using to all cases, instead finding answer just for special condition.*

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var isPressing: Bool = Bool()
    let frameOfView: CGSize = CGSize(width: 300.0, height: 300.0)
    
    var body: some View {
        
        Color.red
            .overlay(Color.yellow.frame(width: frameOfView.width, height: frameOfView.height).gesture(gesture))

    }
    
    private var gesture: some Gesture {

        DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0.0, coordinateSpace: .local)
            .onEnded() { value in

                print("isInside =", isInside(frame: frameOfView, location: value.location, coordinateSpace: .local))

            }
        
    }

    func isInside(frame: CGSize, location: CGPoint, coordinateSpace: CoordinateSpace) -> Bool {

        if (coordinateSpace.isLocal) {
            return (location.x >= 0.0) && (location.y >= 0.0) && (location.x <= frame.width) && (location.y <= frame.height)
        }
        else if (coordinateSpace.isGlobal) {
            return false // under edit!
        }
        else {
            return false // under edit!
        }
        
    }
  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pass in the `Shape` of the view you are using, and use that to determine the path for the shape of the view. You can then test if the last point dragged was inside or outside of this shape.

This is usually just a `Rectangle()`, aka a rectangular view, so in my example there is even a convenience initializer if you don't want to provide this every time.

Code:

```
struct TapReleaseDetector<ContentShape: Shape, Content: View>: View {
    typealias TapAction = (Bool) -> Void

    private let shape: ContentShape
    private let content: () -> Content
    private let action: TapAction
    @State private var path: Path?

    init(shape: ContentShape, @ViewBuilder content: @escaping () -> Content, action: @escaping TapAction) {
        self.shape = shape
        self.content = content
        self.action = action
    }

    init(@ViewBuilder content: @escaping () -> Content, action: @escaping TapAction) where ContentShape == Rectangle {
        self.init(shape: Rectangle(), content: content, action: action)
    }

    var body: some View {
        content()
            .background(
                GeometryReader { geo in
                    Color.clear.onAppear {
                        path = shape.path(in: geo.frame(in: .local))
                    }
                }
            )
            .gesture(gesture)
    }

    private var gesture: some Gesture {
        DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0.0, coordinateSpace: .local)
            .onEnded { drag in
                guard let path = path else { return }
                action(path.contains(drag.location))
            }
    }
}
```

Example usage:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var result: Bool?
    @State private var opacity: Double = 0
    @State private var currentId = UUID()

    private var resultText: String? {
        if let result = result {
            return result ? "Inside" : "Outside"
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 30) {
            Text(resultText ?? " ")
                .font(.title)
                .opacity(opacity)

            TapReleaseDetector(shape: Circle()) {
                Circle()
                    .fill(Color.red)
                    .frame(width: 300, height: 300)
            } action: { isInside in
                result = isInside
                opacity = 1

                withAnimation(.easeOut(duration: 1)) {
                    opacity = 0
                }

                let tempId = UUID()
                currentId = tempId

                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
                    guard tempId == currentId else { return }
                    result = nil
                }
            }

            Text("Recent: \(resultText ?? "None")")
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Okay, thanks I will try your code and will tell you the results.

Comment: It works perfectly even better than what I wanted! thanks